# Suppose $f$ is continuous in $[0, b]$

Tags: derivatives

Suppose $f$ is continuous in $[0, b]$ and differentiable in $(0, b)$. If $f(b) = 0$, show there is a point $c ∈ (0,b)$ for which $g′(c) = 0$, where $g(x) = xf(x)$.

Comment: We (well, at least some of us) wait for your own thoughts on the problem. Where do you get stuck?

Comment: @mickep Sorry, I forgot to wait...;-)

Comment: Please don't simply post homework problems here for others to do. If you have attempted the problem yourself, explain where you got stuck. And give the source of the problem, as well. You can edit the post to add this information.

Answer (score 3):

Note that $g(0)=g(b)=0$ Now apply Rolles Theorem or the mean value theorem.